# Python отправить фотографию в чат из альбома

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, aiohttp

Я пытаюсь отправить фотографию из альбома, можете на примере показать как это сделать пожалуйста

```py
@command(name="тест")
async def upload_photo(self, server, *urls):
     try:
         async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
             files = aiohttp.FormData()
             for i, url in enumerate(urls):
                 imbts = await client.get(url)
                 cnt = imbts.content_type
                 ext = cnt[6:]
                 imbts = await imbts.read()
                 files.add_field(f'file{i}', imbts, filename='temp{}.{}'.format(i, ext))
             res = await client.post(server, data=files)
             photos = await res.json(content_type='text/html')
         payload = {
             'album_id': photos['aid'],
             'group_id': photos['gid'],
             'server': photos['server'],
             'photos_list': photos['photos_list'],
             'hash': photos['hash']
         }
         res = await self.bot.user_vk_request('photos.save', **payload)
         uploaded = res['response']
         return [f'photo{file["owner_id"]}_{file["id"]}' for file in uploaded]
     except Exception:
         raise Exception('Произошла ошибка')
```

В `res = await client.post(server, data=files)`  показывает ошибку: `TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str`

Answer (score 0):

Такая ошибка в этом месте может возникнуть, когда вы передаёте в `client.post` в качестве URL что-то, отличное от строки (о чём и сообщает ошибка в немного непонятной форме). Проверьте внимательно, что именно вы передаёте в качестве параметра `server`.